# Cannot dispose/destroy WebRTC RTCPeerConnection

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have an issue where RTCPeerConnection is not being garbage collected after being created via user interaction. The instances remain in `chrome://webrtc-internals/` indefinitely and eventually users see an error about not being able to create new instances. I've reduced this down to a simple test page and this what I have:

```
<script>
    let pc

    function createPeerConnection() {
        console.log("CREATE CONNECTION")
        pc = new RTCPeerConnection()
    }

    function destroyPeerConnection() {
        console.log("DISPOSE CONNECTION")
        if (pc) {
            pc.close()
            pc = null
        }
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        createPeerConnection()
        setTimeout(destroyPeerConnection, 2000)
    }, 1000)

</script>

<div>
    <button onClick="javascript:createPeerConnection()">CREATE</button>
    <button onClick="javascript:destroyPeerConnection()">DESTROY</button>
</div>
```

Interesting points to note:

- On page load the timeout fires and creates, then destroys an instance, and this seems to work (instance disappears from webrtc internals after 5-10 seconds)
- When clicking CREATE and DESTROY buttons, instances are not removed (they appear in webrtc internals indefinitely)

What am I doing wrong - feel like it must be something very simple. Any pointers much appreciated!

EDIT
In webrtc internals for the connection that is not being disposed I can see a media stream is still attached...

[image]

However, I am running the following code when closing the call:

```
            console.log("DISPOSE CONNECTION")
            pc.onsignalingstatechange = null
            pc.onconnectionstatechange = null
            pc.onnegotiationneeded = null
            pc.onicecandidate = null
            pc.ontrack = null
            pc.getSenders().forEach(sender => {
                console.log("STOP SENDER", sender)
                pc.removeTrack(sender)
                sender.setStreams()
                sender.track?.stop()
            })
            pc.getReceivers().forEach(receiver => {
                receiver.track?.stop()
            })
            pc.getTransceivers().forEach(transceiver => {
                pc.removeTrack(transceiver.sender)
                transceiver.sender.setStreams()
                transceiver.sender.track?.stop()
                transceiver.stop()
            })
            pc.close()
```

Comment: It does seem with this sample code the connection is eventually disposed (after several minutes rather than several seconds), but is not being in my full React app even though pattern is the same...

Comment: this is a known bug in chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=825576

Comment: Thanks @PhilippHancke, I had found that bug report but I don't think it's my problem. In my main React app, the connection _never_ gets disposed. I can leave it more than an hour and it is still there. It must be something to do with the event handlers or attached streams, but I am removing them all and stopping all the tracks so am stumped!